# turtlebot_bringup error - invalid <param> tag

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed turtlebot packages from debs. When I run minimal.launch I get the following error

```
while processing /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/_robot.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: no such command [/opt/ros/groovy/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro']. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
```

I am getting this error after running ubuntu updates this afternoon. I did not get it before the update. Is anyone else getting the same error ?

Thanks,

Prasanna

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57161/turtlebot_bringup-error----invalid-%3Cparam%3E-tag/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-05**:
I never update Ubuntu. This helps a lot ;-)

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-06**:
I have the same error than you, can you keep me up to date if you solve the problem or if a bug fix is released ? Thanks !

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-06**:
@CarolineQ Your advice to update Ubuntu, wasn't it ;) Sure I ll update..

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-06**:
@prasanna It works for me the first time I did it...  But not this time ! Sorry !

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-06**:
New version of xacro has been released yesterday (now version 1.7.3). Download and test it to see if it solves your problem.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-06**:
I downloaded a new version of xacro doing : "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-xacro" and it works fine for me now, even with the roslaunch command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably hitting the bug in the new version of xacro, which has been introduced when catkinizing it.

Have a look at this ticket for more details: https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/1

The bug fix should soon be pushed to public.

Please report back, if you are still having issues after the update.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-06**:
Guys, I'm sorry to inform you that you need to wait a bit longer for a bug fix. The bug fix in xacro release 1.7.3 only solves the problem of 'rosrun xacro xacro.py ...', but not the roslaunch issue. Follow this ticket for more details: https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/2

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-07**:
@bit-pirate I installed the new xacro release and now the roslaunch works fine except for the laptop battery warning which I have described here - http://answers.ros.org/question/56704/turtlebot-2-errors/?comment=57279#comment-57279

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-10**:
@prasanna.kumar Thanks for the info. Just triggered my updates ... PS: Since your question/problem looks to be answered/solved, please mark it accordingly. Thank you!